# Why doesn't my /etc/network/interfaces show anything besides the loopback interface?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns

My goal is to configure DNS servers on the client side.
I was following the guide at: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution.
My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks nothing like the example in the guide.
When I `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, I get:
`# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`
and nothing else...

Comment: You are following a *serverguide* - is your system actually running the server version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No - I am running Ubuntu Desktop, but I'm trying to set up a DNS server on it.

Comment: Not only what steeldriver has mentioned here, what version of Ubuntu are you running?  Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.10 handle networking completely different.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you clients going to be static or dynamic on their IP addresses?  Also, Ubuntu uses Network Manager so you will not see those entries, but you add them for static IPs as once they are added they will override Network Manager settings.  If they are dynamic, you add the entries into `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original` that way resolvconf -u will update the `/etc/resolv.conf` for the DNS server entries.

Comment: I could configure them either way, I suppose. Which way would be easier?

Comment: That is up to you.  Either way you are editing a file to force the DNS on it.  Usually when using DHCP you can assign the DNS from the DHCP server then it will hand it to each host.  When it is static, then you assign it on each host manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75014/discussion-between-mark-and-terrance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following, and it solved my issue:

1. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, including these lines:
   `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2`
   `dns-search example.com`
2. Restart networking services:
   `sudo ifconfig enp4s0 down && sudo ip addr flush dev enp4s0 && sudo ifconfig enp4s0 up`
3. Check that settings were applied:
   `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
   Name servers and search domain should be present.